# How to keep user session after deploying laravel website with ecs

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, amazon-ecs

I am using ECS to deploy my laravel website, no load balancer, only 1 ec2 instance, session is serving by elasticCache redis with phpredis. After every time I deploy my app with ecs-cli compose up,
all user will be logged out from my website. I have installed phpredis and set persistent in laravel config file. Thanks for advise. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Post your compose file

Comment: save sessions in hard drive. change your session driver. better way is using git for deployment.